# Storing Credit Card Info online using iOS app

Tags: ios, credit-card

We are building a mobile app and want people to be able to enter in their credit card information once and store them online using a third party if possible. We want to process their credit card thru the app only when it is required. I am not sure if paypal does that but I did not find anything in their iOS SDK. Can somebody please let me know the best way to do that? Remember this is a mobile app not a web app.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Keychain API for iOS, though you could save the information using NSUserDefault, it likely wouldn't be secure(I wouldn't be able instruct you on how to hash/secure it). You're legally not allowed to save the 3 digit security code, so you'll still have to confirm that when the user is checking out on your app.

Comment: I want to store it somewhere online.. IF I store it in the app, we wont have any control over the user